# How to populate html content to a div from json result using amp-bind component

Tags: json, iframe, laravel-5, accelerated-mobile-page, amp-bind

I have tried the following

Json result

```
{
 "details":"<h1>Heading</h1><p>Description</p>"
}

<amp-state id="remoteData" src="/api/get-result" >
</amp-state>

<div [text]="remoteData.details"></div>
```

Now its showing like the following

```
<div [text]="remoteData.details"><h1>Heading</h1><p>Description</p></div>
```

html tags are listed as text.Actually json result is coming from an api call.Is there any way to achieve this.

I have also tried to load it using amp-iframe. Created an additional page on the server and called the same using iframe. Content is loading properly on that but I am unable to resize the `div` according to content height as both origin are the same.

```
<amp-iframe width="200" id="myframe" height="40" layout="responsive" resizable sandbox="allow-scripts " frameborder="0"                                         src="https://demo.com/api/get-html"></amp-iframe>
```

script used for dynamically setting height of parent amp-iframe component

```
<script>
window.parent.postMessage({
    sentinel: 'amp',
    type: 'embed-size',
    height: document.body.scrollHeight
}, '*');
</script>
```

Using amp-bind I am not able to display the html content,using amp-iframe I am not able to adjust iframe height according to content.Can anyone help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with an amp-list / mustache template. however you're still restricted with a specific height. and you can't inject arbitrary html. Better to render the content on the server side.

if you format your json like so:

```
{
    "items" : [ { 
        "heading":"Heading",
        "description":"Description",
        "listItems": ["one", "two", "three"]
    } ]
}
```

mustache template.

```
<amp-list width="auto" height="50" src="https://myserver/stuff/remoteData.json" max-items="1">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        <h1>{{heading}}</h1>
        <p>{{{description}}}</p>
        {{#listItems}}
            <li>{{.}}</li>
        {{/listItems}}
    </template>
</amp-list>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, I got your point but suppose if I have sub headings or ordered list inside my description.Will that be displayed properly?

Comment: Amp doesn't allow you to inject arbitrary html after the render. Your mustache template(s) would have to allow for all types of formatting. Have you considered injecting the html on the server side?

Comment: The mustache docs specifically say regarding arbitrary html: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-mustache

"Output arbitrary HTML using {{{unescaped}}}. The output of "triple-mustache" is sanitized to only allow formatting tags such as <b>, <i>, and so on."